# How to include a stream in ffmpeg output? (Output file #0 does not contain any stream)

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, video-processing, web-audio-api

This question has been asked many times and I have tried most of the proposed solutions to no avail.

With this command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i dummy.jpg -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

I can create a "dummy" .mp4 file that lasts 10 seconds with a fixed image (dummy.jpg).

This mp4 file plays fine in "QuickTime Player".

However, running `ffmpeg -v error output.mp4 -f null` outputs:

```
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

The Web Audio API (`AudioContext.decodeAudioData`) can't decode this file and the cause is probably the error reported by `ffmpeg`.

How can I include and stream in `output.mp4`?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first command is fine. The second command is missing the input `-i` and is also missing an output name, which is required syntax when using the [null muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#null).

```
ffmpeg -v error -i output.mp4 -f null -
```

The `-` is just a placeholder: no file named `-` is actually being written.

I can't comment on the Web Audio API, since I've never heard of that, but the file doesn't have audio if that makes a difference.